Understanding Character Limits in Twitter Quotes with Tweepy
I'm trying to understand the character limit on Twitter when quoting someone. On Twitter, if I quote a tweet, the quote doesn't count towards the 280-character limit because it is done natively. However, when using Tweepy in Python, if I post something like this:
https://x.com/MarioNawfal/status/1828008451076657550
the link does count towards the character limit. Is there any way to prevent the URL from counting against the character quota per tweet? Or is using a URL shortener the only solution?
